# Montar um array com resultado de um foreach com php

Tags: php, array, foreach

Olá!

Não estou conseguindo montar um array com resultados de um foreach.

Tenho e foreach

```
foreach($Result as $Aluno):
    extract($Aluno);

    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td class='nome'>{$Nome}</td>";
    echo "<td class='centro'>{$finalNota}</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
endforeach;
```

Exibindo:

```
Aluno | Pontuação
Pedro | 1.5
Ana   | 3
Maria | 5.2
José  | 4
```

Estou precisando montar um array com a pontuação tendo assim:

```
Array
(
    0 => 1.5
    1 => 3
    2 => 5.2
    3 => 4
)
```

Obrigado

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

faz assim no seu cod

```
foreach($Result as $Aluno):
    extract($Aluno);

    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td class='nome'>{$Nome}</td>";
    echo "<td class='centro'>{$finalNota}</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
endforeach;
```

transforma ele nisto:

```
$notas=array();
foreach($Result as $Aluno):
    extract($Aluno);

    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td class='nome'>{$Nome}</td>";
    echo "<td class='centro'>{$finalNota}</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
    $notas[]=$finalNota;
endforeach;
```

ao final do `foreach` vc ja tem o array notas do jeito q vc quer.